# Should CoRegisterClassObject and RegisterActiveObject be used at the same time?

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

The title I am sure is confusing, but I cannot really pinpoint the issue.

I am following [this MS example to create an Out-of-Process Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/977996/how-to-develop-an-out-of-process-com-component-by-using-visual-c-,-visual-c-,-or-visual-basic-.net) I have no problems with it.  I can compile, register call CreateObject from VBA and when VBA closes so too does my COM Server.

**Question 1:** I dont understand the need to call CoRegisterClassObject and pass it a reference to an object that Implements IClassFactory when the EXE starts.

I read that this is needed to "register my object" but when I call for example from VBA CreateObject it is only after I call this that the EXE is started and CoRegisterClassObject is used.

**Edit Code added**

```
Dim hResult As Integer = COMNative.CoRegisterClassObject( _
    clsidSimpleObj, New VBSimpleObjectClassFactory, CLSCTX.LOCAL_SERVER, _
    REGCLS.SUSPENDED Or REGCLS.MULTIPLEUSE, Me._cookieSimpleObj)
```

**Question 2:**How do I get an instance of my class object within the EXE server so that I can call RegisterActiveObject?  Please forgive me if I have the wrong terminology.

This is the implemented CreateInstance method.  You see that currently they use in there "New VBSimpleObject".

```
Public Function CreateInstance(ByVal pUnkOuter As IntPtr, ByRef riid As Guid, _
                               <Out()> ByRef ppvObject As IntPtr) As Integer _
                               Implements IClassFactory.CreateInstance

    ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero

    If (pUnkOuter <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
        ' The pUnkOuter parameter was non-NULL and the object does 
        ' not support aggregation.
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(COMNative.CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION)
    End If

    If ((riid = New Guid(VBSimpleObject.ClassId)) OrElse _
        (riid = New Guid(COMNative.IID_IDispatch)) OrElse _
        (riid = New Guid(COMNative.IID_IUnknown))) Then
        ' Create the instance of the .NET object
        ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject( _
         New VBSimpleObject, GetType(VBSimpleObject).GetInterface("_VBSimpleObject"))
    Else
        ' The object that ppvObject points to does not support the 
        ' interface identified by riid.
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(COMNative.E_NOINTERFACE)
    End If

    Return 0  ' S_OK
End Function
```

To call the RegisterActiveObject I think I need a reference to VBSimpleObject

```
 <DllImport("oleaut32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function RegisterActiveObject(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> ByVal pUnk As Object, _
                                            ByRef rclsid As Guid, ByVal dwFlags As IntPtr, _
                                            <Out()> ByRef lpdwRegister As UInt32) As Integer
End Function
```

So how do I pass a reference of VBSimpleObject to the RegisterActiveObject.  I tried making VBSimpleObject a Public variable of the EXE and then just passing CreateInstance this variable, but I dont think this is right.

I am sorry I am a little lost.  If I could find a  C# example which shows how to do both CoRegisterClassObject and RegisterActiveObject I could work it out (Thus I will add a C# tag to alert the C# people).  I have found a [C++ example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221186(v=vs.85).aspx) but I am struggling to understand, it seems as though they either call CoRegisterClassObject or RegisterActiveObject. Is that correct?

Comment: **Answer 1**: how else would `CoCreateInstance` obtain a pointer to your object? `CoCreateInstance` (which is what `CreateObject` ultimately uses) starts the EXE (if necessary), then waits for it to call `CoRegisterClassObject`, grabs `IClassFactory` pointer thus registered, and calls its `CreateInstance` to obtain the actual object.

Comment: **Answer 2**: if you don't have a single object instance naturally representing your coclass, then perhaps it's unwise to try to call `RegisterActiveObject` in the first place. You don't have to.

Comment: Thanks Igor. Re: Answer 1.  I just worked that out by "MsgBox" :-) The series of events I see are VBA calls CreateObject, EXE is started and calls CoRegisterClassObject which then allows for the CreateInstance method in the IClassFactory to be called.

Comment: Re: Answer 2. Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding here but I need to call RegisterActiveObject so that GetObject works and VBA can get a running instance of my EXE.

Comment: What do you pass for the fourth parameter of `CoRegisterClassObject`? Pass `REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE`, then all `CreateInstance` calls will go to the same, already-started EXE instance. They'll just keep calling `CreateInstance` on the class factory the EXE registered when it started.

Comment: I updated the question with the code. REGCLS.SUSPENDED Or REGCLS.MULTIPLEUSE is passed.

Comment: Are you then calling `CoResumeClassObjects`? It's not clear why you need `SUSPENDED` in the first place, but if you choose to, then you need to follow up with `CoResumeClassObjects`. Anyway - are you saying multiple calls to `CreateObject` start multiple instances of your EXE, despite passing `MULTIPLEUSE`? Why do you want to use `GetObject`, specifically?

Comment: Yes "hResult = COMNative.CoResumeClassObjects" is called immediately afterwards. Why Specifically? I believe a VBA client should call CreateObject to create a new instance of the EXE and GetObject to get a running instance. I will check about whether it creates multiple instances.

Comment: You can drop both `SUSPENDED` flag and `CoResumeClassObjects` call. That's a side track though. Let's get back - what is the problem you are trying to solve? Is there a particular reason you want to use `GetObject` and not `CreateObject`?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping. If I start the EXE and call CreateObject it does not start a new instance. So you are right I only have to call CreateObject.  But when VBA sets the object to nothing, the COM server closes down even if the EXE was manually started by me.

Comment: If you want to distinguish between "manually started" and "started via `CoCreateInstance`", look at the command line: the latter passes `Embedding` there. Now, COM doesn't magically terminate the EXE when the last object is destroyed - it's up to the EXE to decide when to shut down. It is common for an EXE COM server to keep a count of all outstanding objects, and to shut down when that count reaches zero. (to be continued)

Comment: If you are looking at a code [like this](https://github.com/cubika/OneCode/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202008/VBExeCOMServer/VBSimpleObject.vb), that happens in `ExeCOMServer.Instance.Lock()` and `Unlock()` (at the bottom). Therefore, one way to keep the EXE running is to manually call `Lock()` once additional time, to prevent the count from reaching zero.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking at.  Thank you so much for setting me on the right path.  I think I have it.